# What is the most elegant tidyverse-style method for splitting data into multiple overlapping subgroups

Tags: r, dplyr, functional-programming, tidyverse, purrr

I am working on a project that involves a binary response variable, a binary treatment classifier, and some other categorical and continuous covariates that were significant in our univariate analysis. My current research question relates to potential interaction effects of the treatment and the participant covariates.

My dataset is already partitioned into 3 partially-overlapping groups of participants.

I wish to test the hypothesis of potential interaction between treatment and covariates by modeling the main effects of each predictor variable (treatment and covariates) and apply a series of logistic regression model that each include one pair of treatment:covariate interactions.

The example can be represented as follows:

```
# Create a dataset with 3 partially overlapping groups
x <- 
  tibble(id = 1:50,
       outcome = rbinom(50, size = 1, 0.5),
       intervention = rbinom(50, size = 1, 0.5),
       p1 = rbinom(50, size = 1, 0.5),
       p2 = rbinom(50, size = 1, 0.5),
       p3 = rbinom(50, size = 1, 0.5),
       p4 = rnorm(50, 50, 10)) %>% 
  list(d1 = ., 
       d2 = (slice(., sample(1:50, size = 40, replace = FALSE))),
       d3 = (slice(., sample(1:50, size = 45, replace = FALSE)))) %>% 
  enframe(name = "subset") %>% 
  unnest(value) %>% 
  mutate_at(1:7, as.character)

c <- paste0("p", 1:4)

# Formula with partially-specified interaction term
f <- "outcome ~ intervention + p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + intervention:"
```

**My question is: what is the most tidyverse-consistent manner in which to do this? What are the various alternatives. Ultimately, which is the most efficient in terms of brevity of code and readability?**

Here is an example of a solution that is a bit hackerish. I can come up with several more off the top of my head, but none that are particularly elegant.

```
f <- "outcome ~ intervention + p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + intervention:"

x %>% 
  mutate_at("p4", function(x) as.character(0)) %>% 
  select(-outcome, -intervention) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c("p1", "p2", "p3", "p4")) %>% 
  select(-value) %>% 
  left_join(x, by = c("subset", "id")) %>% 
  group_by(subset, name) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  mutate(fit = map2(data, name, 
                    ~glm(as.formula(paste0(f, .y)), .x, family = "binomial")))
```

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: check group_map ()

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow, but for some reason, reading the documentation reminded me of the complete function...after re-reading its documentation and that of "expand", I've posted a potential solution below. I know it was quick turn-around, but this has been bugging me for a week, and yet as soon as I post to stack overflow, I think of a potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

Scouring google and thinking about this question all week, I come up with a likely solution mere minutes after posting here. I would welcome alternative approaches though!

```
x %>% 
  expand(nesting(subset, id), name = c("p1", "p2", "p3", "p4")) %>% 
  left_join(x, by = c("subset", "id")) %>%
  group_by(subset, name) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  mutate(fit = map2(data, name, 
                    ~glm(as.formula(paste0(f, .y)), .x, family = "binomial")))
```